# Where should factories live in a project?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, factory-pattern

I have a solution with a project called `MudEngine.Core`. This project contains some essential classes and then all of the interfaces that my domain objects are abstracted behind. Interfaces like `IWorld` and `IRealm`.

#### Example domain interface

```
public interface IWorld : IGameComponent, ICloneableComponent<IWorld>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets how many hours it takes to complete one full day in this world.
    /// </summary>
    int HoursPerDay { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the game day to real hour ratio.
    /// </summary>
    double GameDayToRealHourRatio { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a collection of realms to world, initializing them as they are added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="realms">The realms.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns an awaitable Task
    /// </returns>
    IRealm[] GetRealmsInWorld();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes and then adds the given realm to this world instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="realm">The realm to add.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    Task AddRealmToWorld(IRealm realm);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new instance of a realm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="owner">The world that owns this realm.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an initialized instance of IRealm</returns>
    Task<IRealm> CreateRealm(string name, IWorld owner);

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a collection of realms to world, initializing them as they are added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="realms">The realms.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    Task AddRealmsToWorld(IEnumerable<IRealm> realms);

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the given realm from this world instance, deleting the realm in the process.
    /// If it must be reused, you may clone the realm and add the clone to another world.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="realm">The realm to remove.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    Task RemoveRealmFromWorld(IRealm realm);

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a collection of realms from this world instance.
    /// If any of the realms don't exist in the world, they will be ignored.
    /// The realms will be deleted during the process.
    /// If they must be reused, you may clone the realm and add the clone to another world.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="realms">The realms collection.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an awaitable Task</returns>
    Task RemoveRealmsFromWorld(IEnumerable<IRealm> realms);
}
```

I also have a project called `MudEngine.Mud` which is the default implementations for all of the interfaces.

The `MudEngine.Core` project includes interfaces for my factories. Factories like `IWorldFactory` and `IRealmFactory`. The IWorld interface has a creation method, that uses a given `IRealmFactory` to create realms and return them.

#### Example factory interface

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides methods for creating an instance of an IRealm implementation
/// </summary>
public interface IRealmFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new instance of a realm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="owner">The world that owns this realm.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an initialized instance of IRealm</returns>
    Task<IRealm> CreateRealm(string name, IWorld owner);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new instance of a realm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="owner">The world that owns this realm.</param>
    /// <param name="timeZoneOffset">The time zone offset to apply to the realm.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an initialized instance of IRealm</returns>
    Task<IRealm> CreateRealm(string name, IWorld owner, ITimeOfDay timeZoneOffset);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new instance of a realm.
    /// All of the children zones will be initialized prior to being added to the realm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="owner">The world that owns this realm.</param>
    /// <param name="zones">A collection of zones that will be initialized and added to the realm.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an initialized instance of IRealm</returns>
    Task<IRealm> CreateRealm(string name, IWorld owner, IEnumerable<IZone> zones);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new instance of a realm.
    /// All of the children zones will be initialized prior to being added to the realm.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="owner">The world that owns this realm.</param>
    /// <param name="timeZoneOffset">The time zone offset to apply to the realm.</param>
    /// <param name="zones">A collection of zones that will be initialized and added to the realm.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an initialized instance of IRealm</returns>
    Task<IRealm> CreateRealm(string name, IWorld owner, ITimeOfDay timeZoneOffset, IEnumerable<IZone> zones);
}
```

When I call `CreateRealm` on the IWorld interface, the implementation uses an IRealmFactory to create it. The factory is passed in through the IWorld implementation's constructor.

My question now is, where should the factory implementation exist? Is it common for the same project that contains the domain interface implementations to provide an implementation for the factory or should the consuming layer (such as the presentation/unit test projects) be responsible for implementing the factories and using them?

The intent is that these components can be swapped out depending on the kind of text-based game you are building. So I was leaning towards each package implementing the interfaces having their own factory. What I am concerned with though is the DI setup. The IoC container further up in the layering (server/client apps) would need to know which factory in each package it should use, as opposed to just using one that is defined in the consuming layer that the IoC container is a part of.

Is there any industry standard guidance on this?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things. A Di Container is a factory itself and it's usually configured when the app starts. Personally I have autofac modules in any project/component. If you need a real factory, one where you create objects based on some specific rules, that is part of your domain because it encapsulates domain rules. And there isn't any industry standards for this.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger "depending on the kind of text-based game you are *building*" => does that imply that the application's user is a game administrator ? Or even, he has to write the module for his game, and thus implement `IRealmFactory`, himself ?

Comment: @guillaume31 someone who wants to build a Mud would have to be a game admin, building the content. They can choose from a series of different setups, like a D&D build or a Pathfinder build. I provide different implementations for the classes as plugins and they pick which to run with via an editor. They'd only have to build a custom Irealm if they didn't like what was available. I didn't want to box the engine into preventing people from extending it.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but why would you have to pass an `IWorld` to `IWorld.CreateRealm`? Would you really use an instance of a world to create a realm that belongs to another world instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to build a domain model with abstracted subdomains (I guess you can call them subdomains because they are full fledged game systems), i.e. the user can dynamically pick a subdomain at runtime which triggers some subdomain-agnostic behavior, then do subdomain-specific stuff with it for some period of time and potentially jump to another one when they're finished.

Though in my experience you rarely encounter this in "normal" line of business projects, here's what I'd do :

- Create an overarching Bounded Context for generic World and Realm management. Put `IWorld` and `IRealmFactory` there.
- Create a separate Bounded Context for each game system subdomain. They can be whole projects or just namespaces. Write implementations of `IRealmFactory` in these.
- This is I think one of the few instances when using `Container.Resolve(...)` can be legit. Create named registrations in IoC configuration and resolve one of them at any moment to wire up the object subgraph corresponding to one game system.

Comment: I think this mostly answers my question. What I am working towards is supporting middleware in my pipeline that allows others to swap out various sub-systems. Such as the game engines Battle System rules. Use nuget to bring in D&D rules, or Pathfinder rules etc. I think just having each middleware implement the factory makes the most sense. My domain is built expecting DI to inject everything; it doesn't know of the container as I'm leaving that for the server/client side apps.

Comment: I'm not suggesting calling `Container.Resolve()` from the domain layer but application or presentation layer. When I say "wire up the subgraph" I mean for instance DnDRealm Application Service -> DnDRealmFactory domain object -> DnDRealm Repository etc.

Comment: Regarding the concept of "middleware", it's an overloaded term and I'm not sure it's an appropriate use when everything happens in-process (as it seems from your description).